# can any body help me with this code of multiplication matrix by matrix ?

Tags: matrix

this is the code that i write i tried it but it just work for same length matrix and its should work for the two matrix that the columns of the first one as the the rows of the Second ..

```
void msklret(int matrixA[M][N],int matrixB[M][N],int matrixC[M][N],int r1,intc2,int r2)
```

{

```
  int i , j,k,sum;


 for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
 {
for(j=0; j<c2; j++)
 {
 sum = 0;
 for(k=0; k<r2; k++)
 {
sum += matrixA[i][k] * matrixB[k][j]; 
 }
 matrixC[i][j]=sum;
 sum=0;`
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you are looking for the naive algorithm:

This is written in c#

```
 public float[,] MatrixMultiply(float[,] leftMat, float[,] rightMat)
{
   // get the required row and column ranks for both matrices
   int leftRowNum = leftMat.GetLength(0);
   int rightRowNum = rightMat.GetLength(0);
   int leftColNum = leftMat.GetLength(1);
   int rightColNum = rightMat.GetLength(1);


   // Check that the inner dimensions are the same
      if(leftColNum != rightRowNum)
          return null;
   int innerLen = leftColNum;

   // now define resulting matrix dimensions

   float[,] result = new float[leftRowNum,rightColNum];

   // perform the multiplication using 3 nested for loops
   for(int i = 0; i < leftRowNum; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < rightColNum; j++)
        {
              for(int inner = 0; inner < innerLen; inner++)
                 {
                     result[i,j]+= leftMat[i,inner]*rightMat[inner,j];

                 }
        }
    }

    return result;

 }
```

Now your code would be:

```
void msklret(int matrixA[M][N],int matrixB[M][N],int matrixC[M][N],int r1,intc2,int r2)


    float[,] result = MatrixMultiply(MatrixMultiply(matrixA,matrixB),matrixC);
```

Which can also be written:

```
     float[,] result = MatrixMultiply(matrixA,MatrixMultiply(matrixB,matrixC));
```

Given the associative property of matrix multiplication.